# Changing node reference in RedisGraph relationship

Tags: cypher, redisgraph

I'm starting to use RedisGraph and got some good support here and glad there's a community around it :)

I'm currently trying to achieve a basic thing: moving a relation to a different node:

```
(bob:User {uid: 1})-[p:Paid {amount: 5, date: "Feb 5 2021 10:10:05"}]->(alice:User {uid: 2})
```

Bob was mistaken, he didn't pay Alice but John and would like to fix it.

```
(bob)-[p]->(john:User {uid: 3})
```

I must preserve the properties for `[p]` and ideally I would even keep the same id…

Neo4j has the `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes` function does that but I'm not sure how to achieve a similar result in RedisGraph.

There seems to be a way with `SET`, `WITH` and `DELETE` but I couldn't get something grammatically correct that would work.

Any clue about that?

Thanks for sharing! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedisGraph doesn't have an equivalent to the `mergeNodes` functionality, nor does it support changing the endpoint of an existing edge.

As such, you will need to delete the original edge and introduce a new one:

```
MATCH (bob:User {uid: 1})-[p:Paid {amount: 5, date: "Feb 5 2021 10:10:05"}]->(alice:User {uid: 2}) WITH bob, p, {amount: p.amount, date: p.date} AS props MATCH (john:User {uid: 3}) DELETE p CREATE (bob)-[p2:Paid]->(john) SET p2=props
```

This can be simplified a bit if your program is aware of the property values and can use them as literals:

```
MATCH (bob:User {uid: 1})-[p:Paid {amount: 5, date: "Feb 5 2021 10:10:05"}]->(alice:User {uid: 2}) DELETE p CREATE (bob)-[p2:Paid {amount: 5, date: "Feb 5 2021 10:10:05"}]->(john)
```

Either approach will cause the new edge to have the same ID as the previous one, as the edge ID is released by the `DELETE` and immediately reused by the `CREATE`.

Comment: Thanks, I was close but was missing something that you figured! :+1: